# How would I add a class attribute to all input fields with a certain classname in js?

Tags: javascript, forms

This is my function

```
function checkEmpty()
{
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++ )
    {
        if (input[i].value.length <= 0)
        {
            input[i].classList.add("error-class");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            input[i].classList.remove("error-class");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my form

```
<div id="form-div">
    <form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkEmpty()">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="First Name"/> </label>
          <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="Password"/> </label><br>
          <input type="submit" class="button" id="button" value="CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL"/><br>
     </form>
  </div>
```

This is the class to be applied

```
.error-class
{
    background-image: url("../Registration-form/images/icon-error.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I've had difficult time because I'm new to javascript.

Comment: @Andrew Parks. I want to apply the class to all input fields with the class "input". But it's only working in the first field, for first_name.

Comment: What should I put in place then???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to disable submission if there is any input field empty, So you need to remove the `return true/false` from the loop as this will stop the function execution and break the loop, and you need to add a flag called `valid` and check if there is any field is empty set the `valid` flag to false and at the end of the function you check if the valid is `false` disable submission by `return false`

```js
function checkEmpty(e)
{
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
    let valid = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++ )
    {
        if (input[i].value.length <= 0)
        {
            input[i].classList.add("error-class");
            valid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            input[i].classList.remove("error-class");
        }
    }
    if (!valid) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.error-class
{
    background-image: url("../Registration-form/images/icon-error.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: red; /* This for test you can remove it */
}
```

```html
<div id="form-div">
    <form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkEmpty(event)">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="First Name"/> </label>
          <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="Password"/> </label><br>
          <input type="submit" class="button" id="button" value="CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL"/><br>
     </form>
  </div>
```